# container in bootstrap is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap 3.3.6 version dist folder I have a index.html file and which contain the following code but these is not working. With bootstrap folder we have cs,js,font folder and index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <!--script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script-->
  <script src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--h1 class="text-primary">Hello, world!</h1-->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-mid-4">Left Side </div>
      <div class="col-mid-4">Middle</div>
      <div class="col-mid-4">Left Side </div>
    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please check if there is a problem of `css` path

Answer (score -1):

Use `col-md-*` and not `mid`

```html
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">Left Side </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">Middle</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">Left Side </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

heres is the solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script></head>

<body>
  <!--h1 class="text-primary">Hello, world!</h1-->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">Left Side </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4  col-sm-4 col-lg-4">Middle</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">Left Side </div>
    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

check this :https://jsfiddle.net/x4qapovk/3/